# Jquery FadeIn function not working in first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m using the below jQuery to hide a `div` on click of a button. But I found a problem. `fadeIn` is not working the very first time, but the second time its working. How to fix it?

```
<script>
    $(".get-btn").click(function() {
        $(".container").css('z-index', '40');
        $('.container').fadeOut(500)
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(".close-btn").click(function() {
        $(".container-sec").css('z-index', '0');
        $('.container').fadeIn(500)
    });
</script>
```

here is the JSfiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/mmubashirs/zoctx3f3/

Comment: please add HTML to '.container' or provide a fiddle link

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question. Also, check the console for any errors.

Comment: Can you give jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: Why does one function set `z-index` of `.container`, the other does it on `.container-sec`?

Comment: </head>

<body>

   <div class="container">
    
 </div>   <!--......Container ends.......-->
    
    
    
    
    <div class="container-sec">

 </div>   <!--......Container-sec ends.......-->

Comment: here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmubashirs/zoctx3f3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".get-btn" ).click(function() {
    $(".container").css('z-index', '40');
    $('.container').fadeOut(500);
  });

  $( ".close-btn" ).click(function() {
    $(".container-sec").css('z-index', '0');
    $('.container').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Its working but problem is fade is  not working at very first time when we click on contact button.

Comment: remove both the css from the script:
$(".container").css('z-index', '40');
$(".container-sec").css('z-index', '0');

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9hsypwL/) please

```
$( ".get-btn" ).click(function() {
  $(".container").css('z-index', '40');
    $('.container').fadeOut(500)

});


$( ".close-btn" ).click(function() {
  $(".container").css('z-index', '0');
    $('.container').fadeIn(500)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. It works below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".get-btn").click(function() {
        $(".container").css('z-index', '40');
        $('.container').fadeOut(500);
    });
  $(".close-btn").click(function() {
        $(".container-sec").css('z-index', '0');
        $('.container').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button class="get-btn">hide</button>
<button class="close-btn">show</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: is missing `;` create issue on javascript  ?

Comment: `;` has nothing do with OP's issue as `;`s are optional in JS as long the code is not minified -> [http://jsfiddle.net/kc12xu8r/](http://jsfiddle.net/kc12xu8r/)

Comment: The thing is In my html When click on .get-btn, it hides one container and shows one container. That is the only problem that when we first click on get-btn the fade effect is not working, it is showing page immidiately. but after that the fade effects work ok. But when we refresh and click again it dont work in the first time.